# Request response latency time for int-http:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to time an API request I have setup in Spring Integration using an .  The response time should be added as a message header so it can be audited downstream and recorded along with other data.

Both HTTP success and error responses should be timed, e.g. I want to know how long it took for a server to issue a 500 response.  I'm also already using the Retry and CircuitBreaker advice (as I want that functionality).

I've written a custom advice (from [reading the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#custom-advice)) and added to my :

```
public class RequestResponseTimeInterceptor extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RequestResponseTimeInterceptor.class);


protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        Object result = callback.execute();

        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        message = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("requestResponseTime", after - before).build();

        return result;
    }
    catch (MessageHandlingException e) {
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Message modifiedFailedMessage = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(e.getFailedMessage()).setHeader("requestResponseTime", after - before).build();

        throw new MessageHandlingException(modifiedFailedMessage, e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}


<bean id="calculationRetry" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice"/>
<bean id="calculationCircuitBreaker" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice"/>
<bean id="timer" class="com.integration.audit.RequestResponseTimeInterceptor"/>

<int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="timer"/>
        <ref bean="calculationRetry"/>
        <ref bean="calculationCircuitBreaker"/>
</int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

It works by timing between the callback execution.  I had a problem that failed HTTP responses (e.g. HTTP 500) are wrapped in a MessageHandlingException (in Spring Integration, by design), which stops the rest of the advice from finishing and timing the response.

I have solved this in the code sample by catching the exception, adding the response time as a message header, re-creating the exception and throwing it (so it gets picked up by my error channel).  This seems to work OK - but feel like it's not the best solution.  It also times the full duration of any retries (from my Retry advice) rather than the last retry.

Is there a better way to time HTTP request/response that will work nicely with existing Retry advice, and with failed HTTP response codes?

Appreciate your feedback!

**Edit: Based on Artem's information.**

The order of the advice in request-handler-advice-chain is important (it is an ordered chain after all).  So putting the 'timer' at the end of the chain means it only times request/responses, rather than multiple retries or circuit breakers.

I updated the advice based on Artem's comments so it is now actually returning a Message.  I can then read the new "requestResponseTime" header downstream in the pipeline as needed.

Here's the new code:

```
public class RequestResponseTimeInterceptor extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RequestResponseTimeInterceptor.class);

protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> requestMessage) throws Exception {
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        Object result = callback.execute();

        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Message<?> responseMessage = (Message<?>) result;

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(responseMessage.getPayload())
                            .setHeader(MessageHeaderConstants.REQUEST_RESPONSE_TIME, after - before).build();
    }
    catch (MessageHandlingException e) {
        //Catch HTTP errors (e.g. 500s) so we can also time the response
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Message modifiedFailedMessage = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(e.getFailedMessage()).setHeader(MessageHeaderConstants.REQUEST_RESPONSE_TIME, after - before).build();

        //rethrow new exception for error handling
        throw new MessageHandlingException(modifiedFailedMessage, e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}



    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="calculationCircuitBreaker"/>
        <ref bean="calculationRetry"/>
        <ref bean="timer"/>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all think if your timer really should include all the retries. And that doesn’t seem for me valuable to count timeout for opened circuit breaker. I mean that it would be much realist to reorder your advices different way: circuit first, retry and only then timer. This way you will count only real http requests and won’t go to that part with opened circuit.

Regarding your exception concern. That’s definitely is OK to rebuild message with required headers. For this purpose we have introduced a `ErrorMessageStrategy`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/whats-new.html#_errormessagepublisher_and_errormessagestrategy

On the other hand, please, pay attention to the Spring Cloud Sleuth project: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/

Comment: Thanks Artem, I realized I just needed to reorder the advice chain so opened circuit breaker and retries were not counted - this works great now.  Will review your other suggestions and update the original question.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: When I set the "requestResponseTime" header on the message, it is not available downstream in my pipeline as expected.  How can I do this with AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice?

Comment: That's correct, because you don't return that message from your advice. You still do that like `return result;`. You should return a new message with that `requestResponseTime` header and also copy all the request message header. But at the same time the `payload` must be that `result`. Otherwise you just lose the HTTP response :-)

Comment: OK added an edit above - look about right to you?  My tests are passing :) I didn't realize the doInvoke method returns the Message.  Any reason why the return type isn't Message? Also, I found I don't need to copy the headers from the request, _something_ adds them back in when I debug downstream.  Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Well, the contract of the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage()` is not necessarily return strongly the `Message`, but it adapts to any reply anyway. See `AbstractMessageProducingHandler.createOutputMessage()`. Right, the headers from request are copied `shouldCopyRequestHeaders()` is `true` by default. Hope I've answered to all your questions. :-)

Comment: Thanks - My issue is fixed and feel like I understand more about Spring Integration now!